# How raft node in candidate state process Requestvote from other node in candidate

Tags: raft

If raft node in candidate state,its currentTerm is 4 and it votes for itself,then it receive Requestvote contains term is 5.

Do this raft node will vote for the node whose term is 5 and make its currentTerm = 5?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A node in raft always updates term when a higher one is announced. If it will or won't vote for the other node, it will depend on log state. To vote for another node, two conditions must be met: current node did not vote in current term yet and candidate's logs are at least as updates as current node's.

In the original Raft paper - every node has a state and one of registers in that state is "currentTerm". And the definition is - latest term even seen by the node.